# Log in restriction using firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've created a website using firebase authentication system. The website is intended for a specifik group of people which means i want to restrict sign up/log in for this group.

I've been looking around for a solution but haven't been able to find a good one. I got a tip about creating a "whitelist" for the allowed users and changing the security rules so that .read is true for these people. But would this restrict login?

So basically I'm wondering if anyone else has bumped into this problem? Or if anyone has a good solution?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/8nmib7/log_in_restriction_using_firebase_auth/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to set up FireBase Auth using the Email/Password signin provider.
Then, create a backend page/tool to pre-register the users and send them a verification email.

Details found in FireBase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users